# a UITableView object need to Initialization three times？

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I added `UITableView` into `UIViewController` as a subview, however when I set a breakpoint to the `UITableView` dataSource method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   return 1;
}
```

I find the breakpoint hits three times. Why is that?

Comment: It will execute only rows count. Otherwise have you declared numberOfSections Delegate where you gave some no of Section. ?

Comment: Have you used reloadData anywhere?

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan I declared 1 section

Comment: @ArunGupta I didn`t do it

Comment: you have 3 return in number of section delegate method

Comment: @PKT do you know the reason？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are mentioning is a data source method and has nothing to do with initialization. This is just a method being called by the tableview to ask how many rows there are in the table. I wouldn't be too concerned how many times the tableview asks the data source how many rows there are in the table.

I assume you have created your tableview as subview of another view with the interface builder. This is when you initialize the tableview. All objects that are created with interface builder are being initialized in interface builder. Xcode then archives these objects during compilation (Apple calls it freeze drying) and at run time the objects are unarchived.

During unarchiving the objects created with interface builder are then connected with their outlets, laid out on the screen, etc. Then is when the objects perform their calls to their delegates and data sources. This can happen more than once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, what details do you want to know? What problem are you facing that you are trying to solve?